# How can I use sp_xml_preparedocument on result of NTEXT query in SQL 2000?

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2000, types, sqlxml

I know NTEXT is going away and that there are larger best-practices issues here (like storing XML in an NTEXT column), but I have a table containing XML from which I need to pluck a attribute value. This should be easy to do using sp_xml_preparedocument but is made more tricky by the fact that you cannot declare a local variable of type NTEXT and I cannot figure out how to use an expression to specify the XML text passed to the function. I can do it like this in SQL 2005 because of the XML or VARCHAR(MAX) datatypes, but what can I do for SQL 2000?

```
DECLARE @XmlHandle int
DECLARE @ProfileXml xml
SELECT @ProfileXml = ProfileXml FROM ImportProfile WHERE ProfileId = 1

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @XmlHandle output, @ProfileXml

-- Pluck the Folder TemplateId out of the FldTemplateId XML attribute.
SELECT FolderTemplateId
FROM OPENXML( @XmlHandle, '/ImportProfile', 1)
WITH( 
FolderTemplateId int '@FldTemplateId' )

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @XmlHandle
```

The only thing I can come up with for SQL 2000 is to use varchar(8000). Is there really no way to use an expression like the following?

```
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @XmlHandle output, (SELECT ProfileXml FROM ImportProfile WHERE ProfileId = 1)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Great question.. but no solution

Thoughts:

- You can't wrap the SELECT call in a UDF (to create a kind of dummy ntext local var)
- You can't wrap the `sp_xml_preparedocument` call in a scalar UDF (to use in SELECT) because you can't call extended stored procs
- You can't concatenate a call to run dynamically because you'll hit string limits and scop issues
- Ditto a self call using OPENQUERY
- textptr + READTEXT can't be added as a parameter to `sp_xml_preparedocument`

So why does `sp_xml_preparedocument` take ntext as a datatype?

Comment: You can also pass varchar, char, text, etc. so I wouldn't blame sp_xml_preparedocument for that. I tried wrapping the sp_xml_preparedocument in another stored procedure, but I run into the same problem of not being able to use an expression to get the ntext parameter to the wrapping procedure.